# Error on Extract hog Features from image sets of different dimensions in Matlab. ''Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch''

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-extraction

How could I perform hog feature extraction from image set of different dimensions? I am getting this error on last section.
**''Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.''**

```
%% Change Directory
cd('C:\Users\inquisitive\Documents\MATLAB\hog_test');


%% Root Folder
rootFolder = fullfile('D:\HGDatabase');

%% Load Imagesets Database Directory
imgSets = imageSet(rootFolder,'recursive');

%%
{ imgSets.Description } % display all labels on one line
[imgSets.Count]         % show the corresponding count of images

%% determine the smallest amount of images in a category
minSetCount = min([imgSets.Count]); 
imgSets = partition(imgSets, minSetCount, 'randomize');
[imgSets.Count]

%% partioning into training and testing sets
[trainingSet, testSet] = partition(imgSets, 0.2, 'randomize');

*%%CAN'T I SKIP THIS SECTION AND DEFINE hog_16x16 ON LOOP ITSELF WHY I NEED TO PERFORM THIS AT FIRST WITH ONE IMAGE*

img = read(trainingSet(3), 4);
[hog_16x16, vis16x16] = extractHOGFeatures(img,'CellSize',[16 16]);
cellSize = [16 16];
hogFeatureSize = length(hog_16x16);

%%Extracting Hog Features
trainingFeatures = [];
trainingLabels   = [];

for hand = 1:numel(trainingSet)

    numImages = trainingSet(hand).Count;
    features  = zeros(numImages, hogFeatureSize, 'single');

    for i = 1:numImages

        img = read(trainingSet(hand), i);

        % Apply pre-processing steps
        lvl = graythresh(img);
        img = im2bw(img, lvl);

        features(i, :) = extractHOGFeatures(img, 'CellSize', cellSize);
    end


    labels = repmat(trainingSet(hand).Description, numImages, 1);

    trainingFeatures = [trainingFeatures; features];
    trainingLabels   = [trainingLabels;   labels  ];   

end
```

**Other Query:**

1. Which image format work best .jpg or .png? I thought .png would be better? Am i right?
2. I took some pictures and resize them by thinking that it may train in better way? Am i thinking right or wrong? Or is there nothing to do with different size of input. What would you suggest either to perform in same size or image sets with different dimensions.
3. CAN'T I SKIP FOLLOWING SECTION AND DEFINE hog_16x16 ON LOOP ITSELF WHY I NEED TO PERFORM THIS AT FIRST WITH ONE IMAGE? If i can skip how to deal with that case

   ```
   img = read(trainingSet(3), 4);
   [hog_16x16, vis16x16] = extractHOGFeatures(img,'CellSize',[16 16]);
   cellSize = [16 16];
   hogFeatureSize = length(hog_16x16);
   ```

Comment: There is [209 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Subscripted+assignment+dimension+mismatch) tagged with your error on this forum.

Comment: may be i am not asking how many question are there in this forum with this tag. And, do you think that a newbie could tweak the things from other solutions and could fit on mine. Instead of counting how many questions are out there with same tags could you provide me one link that is pretty much similar to mine so that a newbie could understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure the dimensions of the image are the same as all images, then your extracted `hog_16x16` features will have the same dimensions.